# How to create GeoServer layer with native CRS?

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

I try to upload (create) on to GeoServer layers with different CRSes, possible unknown for GeoServer (and not presented in user_projections/epsg.properties).
First I do this, for example:

```
c:\OSGeo4W\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -skipfailures -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='dbgis' host='localhost' port='5432' user='postgres' password='123456'" "be32d51207af4b1a8d0cf6163c282274.mif"
```

Then I do this:

```
C:\curl\bin\curl.exe -u admin:123456 -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<featureType><name>be32d51207af4b1a8d0cf6163c282274</name></featureType>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/a77x7/datastores/PostGis/featuretypes
```

And this:

```
C:\curl\bin\curl.exe -u admin:123456 -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/xml" -d "<layer><enabled>true</enabled></layer>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/be32d51207af4b1a8d0cf6163c282274
```

But setting CRS failed:

```
C:\curl\bin\curl.exe -u admin:123456 -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/xml" -d @"...\crs.xml" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/a77x7/datastores/PostGis/featuretypes/be32d51207af4b1a8d0cf6163c282274
```

Where crs.xml is (by gdalsrsinfo -o wkt ...), for example:

```
<featureType><enabled>true</enabled><nativeCRS>
PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["Pulkovo_1942",SPHEROID["Krassovsky",6378245,298.3],TOWGS84[24,-123,-94,0.02,-0.25,-0.13,1.1]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",75],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",13500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
</nativeCRS><srs>EPSG:4326</srs><projectionPolicy>NONE</projectionPolicy></featureType>
```

GeoServer says "200 OK", but projectionPolicy stays FORCE_DECLARED.
If I set empty srs tag, GeoServer answer "500 Server Error".

How I can publish layers with any CRS in GeoServer through REST?

By web interface projectionPolicy of NONE not saved too (see images).
[image]

[image]

Comment: GeoServer will not accept a projection it does not know about, see http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/crs_handling.html

Answer (score 1):

I partially solved a problem...
If I create featuretype on GeoServer for PostGIS table as one single step then CRS sets as I expected:
Instead of second step of:

```
C:\curl\bin\curl.exe -u admin:123456 -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<featureType><name>be32d51207af4b1a8d0cf6163c282274</name></featureType>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/a77x7/datastores/PostGis/featuretypes
```

I send xml file with full info about feature type:

```
C:\curl\bin\curl.exe -u admin:123456 -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d @"c:\temp\...\be32d51207af4b1a8d0cf6163c282274.a77x7_ftx" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/a77x7/datastores/PostGis/featuretypes
```

Where a77x7_ftx is a my extension of xml file, for example:

```
<featureType><name>be32d51207af4b1a8d0cf6163c282274</name><enabled>true</enabled><nativeCRS>PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["Pulkovo_1942",SPHEROID["Krassovsky",6378245,298.3],TOWGS84[24,-123,-94,0.02,-0.25,-0.13,1.1]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",75],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",13500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
</nativeCRS><projectionPolicy>NONE</projectionPolicy></featureType>
```

And fourth step not needed (as in my original post):

```
C:\curl\bin\curl.exe -u admin:123456 -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/xml" -d @"...\crs.xml" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/a77x7/datastores/PostGis/featuretypes/be32d51207af4b1a8d0cf6163c282274
```

As result GeoServer recognizes native CRS and set it as declared (see image):
[image]